# MYSQL LIKE statement not yielding desired result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table

```
id | vegetable
---+---------------------------------
 1 | Capsicum
 2 | Capsicum, Capsicum (yellow)
 3 | Tomato, Capsicum (red)
 4 | Capsicum
 5 | Capsicum, Potato, Capsicum (red)
```

I want to know the count of all the vegetable types; Capsicum must be counted separately from Capsicum (red) or Capsicum (yellow). I expect a result like this:

```
Capsicum : 4
Capsicum (red): 2
Capsicum (yellow) : 1
Tomato : 1
Potato : 1
```

Individual vegetable is run from an array with foreach loop. If I run this MySQL code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(vegetable) AS tot FROM mytable WHERE vegetable like '%" . $veg . "%'";
```

This is the result:

```
Capsicum : 7 // instead of 4
Capsicum (yellow) : 1
Capsicum (red) : 2
Tomato : 1
Potato : 1
```

What is the workaround to this problem?

Comment: _7 //instead of 4_ why expecting 4? It is 7....

Comment: Why do you expect another result?

Comment: Capsicum is different from Capsicum (red) or Capsicum (yellow) and must be counted separately.

Comment: _Capsicum is different from Capsicum (red)..._ yes but Capsicum = Capsicum when you use `LIKE`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to count rows that include the word 'Capsicum', then you should use count(id).

If your purpose is to count how many times this word ('Capsicum') is repeated in all rows, then i suggest you replace it as follows:

```
select (
        Length(vegetable) - 
        Length(replace(vegetable, 'Capsicum', ''))
       ) /
        Length('Capsicum')
```

Length(vegetable) ... this will give you the length of the whole column, suppose it is 20
Length(replace(vegetable, 'Capsicum', '')) ... this will give you the length after removing the word 'Capsicum', suppose it is 4

The difference is 20 - 4 = 16
this means that the word 'Capsicum' occurred 2 times

To know how many times the word was repeated, let's divide the result (16) over the length of the word 'Capsicum'
16 / 8 = 2 occurrences

Now, let's sum all occurrences

```
select SUM
(
       (
        Length(vegetable) - 
        Length(replace(vegetable, 'Capsicum', ''))
       ) /
        Length('Capsicum')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed working as expected, as it finds 7 records. Your column is most likely enumerable?

My advice would be to normalize the database sceham (1 table with vegetables), 1 table with possible colours and 1 table that combines vegetables with color (since I see you're writing color in the comments), and query the last table that I've wrote.

You can also try an `"group by (vegetable)"` to your query, it should give you an approximate result to what you seek but I'm not entirely sure.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(vegetable) AS tot 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE vegetable like '%" . $veg . "%' 
        GROUP BY (vegetable)";
```

Comment: That doesn't help.

Comment: If you're looking for an explanation, it does. Your like is considering everything to the left and right

Comment: Yes, it does but my requirement is different. I didn't frame the question properly.

Comment: Yousouf's answer would be more accurate, as you would have to work around either your %like% or concatenate the result of the vegetable table

Answer (score 0):

May be DISTINCT keyword could work.